# Is there any way to translate this?

Tags: notepad++, translation, texas-instruments

I'm trying to make an OS for my TI-89 calculator, so I went and got an OS from the TI website.  Upon editing it with N++, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLldM.png).  I've seen this kind of abstract data before with images or other abstract files (e.g. non-text files) and I'm wondering if there's any way to "convert" this data into something readable/editable.

If you have any solutions, please post them below, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need access to whatever compiler was used to create it. For example, if you edit a .jar file in N++ you'll something similar. If you open it in a java compiler, you'll be able to edit code. My $0.02 is it's probably not worth trying to figure it out, though modding my old calculator was always fun!